# Rails loop in html erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I simplify the following lines:

```
<% if @campaign.previous_campaign.present? %>
    <%= @campaign.previous_campaign.product_name %>
    <% if @campaign.previous_campaign.previous_campaign.present? %>
        <%= @campaign.previous_campaign.previous_campaign.product_name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I need to keep adding ".previous_campaign" until it is not present. So the next one in the above code would be:

```
<%= @campaign.previous_campaign.previous_campaign.previous_campaign.product_name %>
```

etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<% campaign = @campaign %>    
<% while campaign.previous_campaign.present? %>
  <% campaign = campaign.previous_campaign %>  
  <%= campaign.product_name %>
<% end %>
```

The code may need some debugging, but I guess the idea is clear

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<% for c in @campaign do %>
  <% if c.previous_campaign.present? %>
    <%= c.previous_campaign.product_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: .previous_campaign is a flag for completed campaigns, when a campaign is done and replaced, the old and new campaigns are connected. So what I am trying to do is see if a previous campaign exists, if so get some info, then see if that previous campaign has a previous campaign as well.. etc etc.

Basically I need to keep adding .previous_campaign like .previous_campaign.previous_campaign.previous_campaign

Until there is no previous campaign.

Comment: @OhHendrie, no it does not. It's an infinite loop

Comment: @OhHendrie " undefined method `each' "

Comment: because @campaign is nil? try using the edited syntax.

Comment: ahh, okay. I assumed that @campaign = Campaign.all